# jQuery + Flash Media Playback or YouTube: call function after flv finishes playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, flv

I have an .flv movie embedded in HTML using [Adobe's Flash Media Playback](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaplayback/). Once the movie finishes playing, is it possible to call a function with jQuery and/or Javascript? Would this be possible with an embedded YouTube video?

Once the movie finishes I need to display some content. At the moment, the user has to click a button to close the movie and continue on to that content and I'd like to remove the need for that click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. If you have access to the actionscript you can use an [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to communicate with javascript. Also, youtube has an javascript api that is very comprehensive and should allow you to determine the status of the video and do whatever you want after it finishes with player.getPlayerState()

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status

Comment: If I could send you a beer... That's perfect. Thank you.